# How to bind a control boolean property to contrary of boolean application setting?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, application-settings

How to bind a control Boolean property to contrary of Boolean application setting?

For example I want to bind "Visible" property of a button to "!Flag", that "Flag" is a Boolean field in application settings.

Comment: Please provide the original code.

Comment: Are you using WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ApplicationSetting binding doesn't allow applying any expression to the value.  The simple solution is to derive your own control from Button.  For example:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyButton : Button {
    public bool Invisible {
        get { return !Visible; }
        set { Visible = !value; }
    }
}
```